# Storyboard animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I made a small WPF application to slide UserControls in and out, the problem I have is when a UserControl animated to slide in, then I click the button to slide another UserControl in, they both slide out - I'm not sure why this is?

```
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void SlideIn(UserControl uc)
{
    ThicknessAnimation tAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation();
    tAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
    tAnimation.From = new Thickness(500, 0, -500, 0);
    tAnimation.To = new Thickness(0);
    tAnimation.DecelerationRatio = 0.9;

    Storyboard.SetTargetName(tAnimation, uc.Name);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(tAnimation, new PropertyPath(MarginProperty));

    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(tAnimation);
    storyboard.Begin(uc);
    this.Content = uc;
}

public void SlideOut(UserControl uc)
{
    ThicknessAnimation tAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation();
    tAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
    tAnimation.To = new Thickness(-500, 0, 500, 0);
    tAnimation.DecelerationRatio = 0.9;

    Storyboard.SetTargetName(tAnimation, uc.Name);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(tAnimation, new PropertyPath(MarginProperty));

    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(tAnimation);
    storyboard.Begin(this);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SlideOut(userControl1);
    UserControl2 uc2 = new UserControl2();
    SlideIn(uc2);
}
```

Comment: I tried `storyboard.Begin(uc);` but the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you set the Name property of the UserControl somewhere? Or to be more precise, do you give the second UserControl a different Name than the first one? Your animations get their target set by

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(tAnimation, uc.Name);
```

so names should be different. Alternatively you may call

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(tAnimation, uc);
```

to specify the target.

Comment: I set the Name property in the XAML, both UserControls have different names. I just tried `Storyboard.SetTarget(tAnimation, uc);` but still the same... If anyone would be interested, I can upload this application if you would like to try?

Comment: I uploaded to Dropbox's Public folder, should be accessible by all - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6727433/MyOwnLibrary.zip

Comment: Ok, the problem is `this.Content = uc` in UserControl1.xaml.cs, line 32. Setting the second UserControl as content of the first makes it move together (slide out) with the first. You should restructure your app and use a container (e.g. Canvas) in the MainWindow for both controls. Add them dynamically to Canvas.Children and animate Canvas.Left and/or Canvas.Top.

Comment: Ah ok. I think what you described in the latter part is shown here: http://www.joeseymour.net/2009/07/wpf-screen-transition.html - I've tried this already. I've been experimenting loads of different transitions libraries, the problem is that I'm working with Kinect and I'm using hover buttons, which don't seem to work after several UserControls are displayed, because most libraries tend to overlap each new UserControl. So I'm really stuck for ideas + don't have a solution for the Kinect thing either.

Comment: Yes, the sample you're referring to looks pretty much like what you're trying to achieve. The most important thing again, concerning the concrete problem you descrive in your question, is to have all the moving controls in the same container and add and remove them dynamically before and after animating their locations. It doesn't matter so much if you use the positioning provided by Canvas or if you choose another approach, e.g. animate the control's RenderTransorm property. Anyway, never forget to accept this answer if it helps with your question.